# Subclassing RegexValidator in Django does not work

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-validation

For the sake of DRY and easyness I want to inherit from [Django's RegexValidator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/validators/#regexvalidator).

I tried this:

```
class UsernameValidator(RegexValidator):
    regex = r'^([a-zA-Z]{4}[\w]{1,16})$'
    message = 'Wrong username format.'
    code = 'invalid_format'
```

And I added this validator to my field this way:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    signup_username = forms.CharField(label='Username', max_length=20,
                                  validators=[UsernameValidator])
```

But the Validator does not fail if I use an wrong Username (like `123` or `abc`).
What's the right way to inherit from `RegexValidator`?

I need this validation at several points, what's why I want an own validator for this.

Answer (score 1):

Create instance of RegexValidator.

```
validate_username = RegexValidator(regex=r'^([a-zA-Z]{4}[\w]{1,16})$',
                                   message = 'Wrong username format.',
                                   code = 'invalid_format')

...validators = [validate_username]...
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an own function instead of subclassing RegexValidator, and that works.

```
def validate_username(value):
    regex = r'^([a-zA-Z]{4}[\w]{1,16})$'
    if not re.match(regex, value):
        raise ValidationError('Wrong username format.')
```

Comment: Nevertheless, I am still curious why my approach posted in my question does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Validators argument should be a list of callable objects
In your case it should be

`validators=[UsernameValidator()]`